# Brackets disabling autocomplete

Tags: jquery, text-editor, brackets

I just started using the text editor Brackets. When I type  it `<`p`>` autocompletes it with the closing tag `<`/p`>`. I tried adjusting the preferences page but after quitting out of the editor and opening it back up, it throws an error that the preference file is in an incorrect .json file.

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": false,
    "closeBrackets": false,
    "smartIndent": false,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace"

    // Sets the tag closing options
    "closeTags": {

    // An array of tags that should not be auto-closed
    "dontCloseTags": ["footer", "img", "p", "section", "article"],

    // An array of tags that when opened has a blank line
    "indentTags": [],

    // Close when / of closing tag is typed
    "whenClosing": true,

    // Close when > of opening tag is typed
    "whenOpening": true
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user guide is located [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences). Go to Debug -> Preferences, which will open a JSON file. Set `closeBrackets` to `false`.

The parser for JSON in brackets is extremely strict. Here is my sample config that worked (after quite a few tries).

```
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "12px",
    "closeBrackets": false,
    "code-folding.enabled": false,
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "closeTags": {
        "dontCloseTags": ["html"],
        "indentTags": [],
        "whenClosing": false
    }
}
```